# Any 'standard' friend selection dialog available w/o FBML?

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-canvas

I'm fairly new to facebook development, so sorry for any stupid questions here. I've developed a canvas based (iframe) app.

I use the request dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to invite friends. Works great.

However, I now need to select a subset of my friends to do something specific with them on my side of things. For example, I want only a subset of my friends to see something in my app.

I build a clunky page that uses the graph API to get the friend list and it works. However, I was hoping there was some user-familiar standard dialog I could use to do this.

What I've found this far is FBML based and thus deprecated. I also found some JS api stuff, but my understanding is that it's for websites, not canvas apps that run server-side primarily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's a nicely built custom friend selector - http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/06/20/the-missing-facebook-interface-component-for-friend-selection/

Comment: hadn't seen that before - nice.

Comment: this does what I'm looking for. I still can't believe facebook doesn't provide a means to do this. are we sure there isn't?

Comment: I'm quite sure. Hopefully they add more customization options in the future, but for now we're handcuffed.